# How to instantiate angular controller for testing with intern

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, intern

I am trying to test an angular controller using the intern testing framework. I have successfully tested angular services. Yet when trying to load the controller using `$controller('myController', { '$scope': scope });`

I get an unknown provider error message.

The options I have are to pass a string which is the name of the controller that has been registered, or to pass the controller as a function. To avoid polluting the global scope I have opted to register the controller using the module().controller() syntax. Which means that I need to pass the name as a string.

The controller is defined as follows:

```
app.controller('UnitsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    'auth',
    function ($scope, $http, auth) {
        // do stuff
    }
]);
```

In the intern test I load the modules like so:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'intern/order!bower_components/angular/angular',
    'intern/order!bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
    'intern/order!public/src/javascripts/app.controllers' ],
    function (registerSuite, assert, ng, ngMock, appControllers) {
```

Then using the object testing notation I register the variable I need throughout the test:

```
registerSuite(function () {
    var $injector, unit, scope, $rootScope,
    $controller, UnitsCtrl, $window;
    return {
        name: 'Units controller',
```

And in the setup function I instantiate the injector, passing the modules required for testing. And instantiate the controller provider and the rootscope.

```
setup: function() {
    $injector = angular.injector(['ng',  app.controllers' ]);
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
```

Finally before each test I try to instantiate the controller under test:

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
UnitsCtrl = $controller('UnitsCtrl', { '$scope': scope });
```

When I run the test this produces the following complaint:

```
! [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: authProvider <- auth <- UnitsCtrl
```

What is perplexing me is why on earth it is looking for UnitsCtrl controller in the auth service?!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the unknown provider complaint was not to do with the controller I was trying to instantiate, but to do with one of it's dependencies. Because I was not loading the services module, the dependancy could not be found (it wasn't registered).

The fix was to mock up the dependency and pass it in to the controller as part of the object that is the second parameter.

```
auth = { //stuff };
UnitsCtrl = $controller('UnitsCtrl', { '$scope': scope, 'auth': auth});
```